# What select in PostgreSQL will return the metadata

Tags: postgresql

I need to query:
All table & view names
For each table & view: their schema, description, & all column names.
For each column: their name, type, & description.
Also for each table, all PK:FK relationships.

We have selects, but they don't seem to fully work on the latest version. For example, we get all tables using:

```
SELECT schemaname, tablename from pg_tables order by tablename
```

And we don't get all tables.

thanks - dave

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pg_views` to get the views:

```
select schemaname, tablename from (
    select schemaname, tablename from pg_tables union all
    select schemaname, viewname from pg_views
) as x
order by tablename
```

Then use [`information_schema.columns`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/infoschema-columns.html) to get all the columns. For example:

```
select
    schemaname,
    tablename,
    (
        select array_agg("column_name"::text)
        from information_schema.columns
        where
            table_schema = x.schemaname and
            table_name = x.tablename
    )
from (
    select schemaname, tablename from pg_tables union all
    select schemaname, viewname from pg_views
) as x
order by tablename
```

`information_schema` has a bunch of other stuff you might also find useful: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/information-schema.html